# 3D web visualization with arbitrary cutting plane

Tags: visualization

How can I visualize 3D data volumes with arbitrary cutting plane on web pages? I could not find a library that allows so.

Comment: What do you mean by "on web pages"? Are you looking for ways to allow users to interact with 3d data?

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth, yes, I am looking for ways to allow users to interact with 3d data on a web browser.